# Compare 2 dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

What is the best way to compare 2 dictionaries? The items within them "should" always be in the same order.

```
dictionary<string, int> _requiredItems = new dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary<string, int> _collectedItems = new dictionary<string, int>();

_requiredItems.Add("Cube", 2); //2 being the number of Cubes required
_collectedItems.Add("Cube", 0); //0 meaning we don't have any collected
_requiredItems.Add("Sphere", 3); //3 being the number of Spheres required
_collectedItems.Add("Sphere", 0); //0 meaning we don't have any collected     

//stuff happens here
int _itemCollected = _itemsCollected["Cube"];
_itemsCollected["Cube"] = _itemCollected++;
```

so now a way to compare them both. if _collectedItems values = _requiredItems values then return true, if not false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, int>>.CreateSetComparer().Compare(
    new HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(dict1),
    new HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(dict1)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ `All` method, e.g.:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();

var result = dict1.All(k => k.Value == dict2[k.Key]);
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if `dict2` is missing keys and will return a false positive if `dict1` is missing keys.

Comment: @SLaks, it will. And? It seems it is not OP's case.